# usage of strcpy in functions 

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, gcc-warning, strcpy

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

struct person *create_node(char *, char *,int);
void addnode(char *,char *,int,struct person *);


struct person
{
   char fname[20];
   char sname[20];
   int pno;
   struct person *next,*prev;
};

struct person *create_node(char *first,char *second,int mob)
{
   struct person *pnode=(struct person *)malloc(sizeof(struct person));
   strcpy(pnode->fname,*first);
   strcpy(pnode->sname,*second);
   pnode->pno=mob;
   pnode->next=pnode->prev=NULL;

  return pnode;

 }

 void addnode(char *first,char *second,int mob,struct person *pnode)
 {
   while(pnode->next!=NULL)
   {
        pnode=pnode->next;
   }
   pnode->next=create_node(first,second,mob);
   pnode->next->prev=pnode;

 }

 int main()
 {
   struct person *root=NULL;
   char choice='y';
   char first[20];
   char second[20];
   int mob;

   while(tolower(choice)=='y')
  {
        printf("enter the first name:");
    scanf("%s",first);

    printf("enter the second name:");
    scanf("%s",second);

    printf("enter the mobile no:");
    scanf("%d",&mob);

    if(root==NULL)
    root=create_node(first,second,mob);
    else
    addnode(first,second,mob,root);
    printf("enter the option to continue or end(y or n):");
    scanf("%c",&choice);
    fflush(stdin);
  }

  return 0;
  }
```

This is the program I have written,what it basically does is,it will create linked list taking the values of the structures from the users.

I got 2 similar warnings when i run this program from the function

```
    struct person * create_node(char *, char *, int),
    passing char to argument 2 of strcpy(char *, const char *) lacks a cast
```

I don't understand why it is passing `const` value to the function.

And I have one more problem with this program.The program stops working after I enter the information for first node.

I am using `gcc` compiler on windows platform.
Please help me out.
Thanks...

Comment: Your code doesn't do any length checking. If anyone enters more than 19 characters in their name, bad things will happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not that. The problem is that you're passing `*first` and `*second` as the second argument for `strcpy()` which are `char`s and not char pointers. You must simply pass `first` and `second`, the pointers themselves.

Also, please [do not cast the return value of malloc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @user1632141 Precisely, which is the warning?

Comment: ANSI C++ forbids implicit conversion from `void *' in initialization

Comment: You tagged this question `c`, not `c++`. If it's actually a `C++` program, you're going to get wrong advice.

Comment: @user1632141 Wow... That's not my fault! You tagged this question as C, this code seems to be C, ... yet you compile/treat it as C++. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
struct person *create_node(char *first,char *second,int mob)
{
   // ...
   strcpy(pnode->fname,*first);
   strcpy(pnode->sname,*second);
   // ...
   return pnode;
}
```

`first` and `second` are pointers (to `char`). There's no reason to dereference them with `*` and extract the chars. `strcpy()` takes pointers as its arguments. `first` and `second` are good for `strcpy()` as they are.